# Converting a byte array into an image using PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html

I'm using PHP to retrieve data from a SOAP service, part of which is a byte array of an image encoded in base64, and I'd like to display that image in the browser.  The data retrieval step works fine, but I can't find a single way to display this image in the browser.
   Assuming that the byte array is stored in PHP as $byteArray:

```
$img = "<img src= 'data:image/jpeg;base64, $byteArray' />";
print($img);
```

I'd expect that code to display an image in the broswer, but the parser for the browser keeps failing.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

An example byteArray that I've used here would be: "[B@14a3da8"

Thanks in advance,
   Brian

Comment: Is `[B@14a3da8` really an actual image? It seems much too short to me.

Comment: I thought so as well, but they're insisting it is.  Do you know of a good way to check if that byte array is a valid image?  I would think this little HTML snippet should be enough of a test, but I obviously can't verify that without seeing it work with a different byteArray

Comment: `@` is no valid character in base64 encoded strings, so something went wrong somewhere in the process.

Comment: why in the world would you have a string variable that holds a base64 encoded string called $byteArray??? If you want to go as far as to say "a string is nothing more than an array anyways" then call it $stringArray.  In either case, it's no longer holding the original binary data in a byte array.  That's like converting $100 USD to Japanese Yen, but still calling it dollars because of it's relative value...

Answer (score 7):

If you run this code :

```
$imgData = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/7gAOQWRvYmUAZAAAAAAA/+0TrFBob3Rvc2hvcCAzLjAAOEJJ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";
echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64, $imgData' />";
```

(Sorry this is a 40x30 pixels image but still huge anyway).

An image will appear.

All of that to say that your syntax is ok :

```
echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64, $imgData' />";
```

Outputs an image if your $imgData contains a real image.

Answer (score 3):

You need to base64 encode the data. This is required and ensures that charset conversions don't touch the data.

The correct code should be

```
$imgData = base64_encode($byteArray);
$img = "<img src= 'data:image/jpeg;base64, $imgData' />";
print($img);
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this before on the assumption that my data partner wasn't actually encoding the image.  When I do this, the image won't error on parse in the browser, but it still shows up as a broken image.  I'm trying to generate my own byteArray to see if the process works with an input that I know is valid.

Comment: You're right, missed the part about it already being encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example of browsing an image file `.jpg` and converting it into base64 byte format and sending it to server.
Server script `php` will decode and save image to server.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function getBase64Image()
{
    var files = document.getElementById('file1').files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++)
    {
      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*'))
      {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {

        var str = e.target.result;
        var res = str.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,","");
        var res = str.replace("data:base64,","");
         $("#tbx_base64").val(res);
         console.log(e.target)
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
     reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}

function submitForm(){    

    //SENDING IMAGE FILE WITH JSON OBJECT. YOU CAN ALSO SEND WITHOUT JSON OBJECT.
    var o = {};
    o.name = "Test";
    o.arr = ["lucky_no":323];
    o.upload_image = $("#tbx_base64").val();    
    $.post("http://localhost/jquery_multiple_file_upload/upload.php/", {o:o}, function(data){   
        alert(data) 
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post" id="form_test">
    <input id="file1" type="file" onChange="getBase64Image()"  />
    <textarea id="tbx_base64" style="display:none"></textarea> <!-- TEXTAREA IS HIDE. AS IT IS ONLY USED TO HOLD BYTE DATA -->
    <input type="button" value="Upload File" id="upload" onClick="submitForm();" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $image_byte_code = $_REQUEST['o'];
    $content = base64_decode($image_byte_code['upload_image']);
    $im = imagecreatefromstring($content);

    if ($im !== false) {
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($im, "uploads/1.jpg");
        imagedestroy($im);
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'An error occurred.';
    }
?>
```