# Postgres: how to use a image as bytea from a database as picture in a <img src > tag?

Tags: php, postgresql-9.1, pg

I have a table in postgres and it has a column in bytea format that contains pictures.
I selected for it and stored the pictures in a array
How can I display them?This do not work:

```
echo "<img src="'.$row['image_small'].'">";
```

later I found out that the pictures seem to be png format. then I tryed something like this

```
echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64, ". $row['image_small']. "' />";
```

but instead to show a picture I get this

```
<img src='data:image/png;base64, \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'>
```

practically visible in the browser is nothing.
Any more hints?

Comment: this could help you **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537856/converting-a-byte-array-into-an-image-using-php-and-html**

Answer (score -1):

first thats a google encoding through json and 2 you need a http url in the database if you had a form make a hidden input type as to where it would go where it would upload (php script) then use the $_POST function to insert the data into the database

Comment: I do not want to insert the picture in the database. It's already there. I want to display it with the <img > tag.

Comment: this is why you must use full url

Comment: What do you mean with full URL ?